# Can DESCRIBE syntax be embedded in SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, information-schema, describe

In MySQL, the syntax `DESCRIBE` can show a table's structure, but it cannot be embedded to normal statement; is there some tricky way to do it?

For example, this shows the `table1` structure, returned as a table (but SQL statement does not think so)

```
DESCRIBE `table1`
```

But this doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM (DESCRIBE `table1`)
```

Is there a way to enable it?

I want to join the "table" created by `DESCRIBE` syntax, how can I do it?

Comment: Why you want this one?

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [**COLUMNS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html) table of **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** to get expected result as an alternate solution of **DESCRIBE** table option.

Try this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS `Field`, COLUMN_TYPE AS `Type`, IS_NULLABLE AS `NULL`, 
       COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`, COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`, EXTRA AS `Extra`
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table1';
```

Answer (score 13):

The output of `DESCRIBE` looks like a table, but `DESCRIBE` is not actually a query and thus cannot be treated as, for example, a subquery in a SELECT statement.