# Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch SQL, SHOW COLUMNS or DESCRIBE - is there a posibility to filter the output

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I have simple elastic SQL query like this:

```
GET /_sql?format=txt
{
  "query" :"""
    DESCRIBE "index_name"
  """
}
```

and it works, and the output is like this:

```
    column                      | type          | mapping    
-----------------------------------------------------------
column_name1                    | STRUCT        | object         
column_name1.Id                 | VARCHAR       | text           
column_name1.Id.keyword         | VARCHAR       | keyword
```

Is there a possibility to the prepare above query using `filter` or `where`, for example something like this:

```
GET /_sql?format=txt
{
  "query":"""
  DESCRIBE "index_name"
  """,
  "filter": {"terms": {"type.keyword": ["STRUCT"]}}
}
```

or

```
GET /_sql?format=txt
{
  "query":"""
  DESCRIBE "index_name"
  WHERE "type" = 'STRUCT'
  """
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, no.

While the `DESCRIBE` sql command *seems* to return tabular data, it is not a query and it does not support `WHERE` clauses or can be used within a `SELECT` statement. That is actually not specific to Elasticsearch, but the same in RDBMs.

The same apparently is true for the Elasticsearch `filter` clause. This again will work with `SELECT` SQL statements, but with `DESCRIBE` or `SHOW COLUMNS` - while not producing an error - it simply will have no effect on the results.

In "real" SQL, you could work around this by querying [`information_schema.COLUMNS`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20769255/14015737), but that is not an option in Elasticsearch.